# Suppress mysql update query output

Tags: mysql

How do i stop mysql from printing the result of a recent UPDATE query?
i.e when we execute a mysql query, we have the following output:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

how do i stop mysql from printing this?

Comment: Are you doing this from command prompt or are you using any tools?

Comment: command prompt.. i'm also using command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [--silent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_silent) when you have the program mysql started.